# Curly quotes in non-default font with xelatex

Tags: fonts, xetex, punctuation

I have the following:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont [Ligatures={Common}, Numbers={OldStyle}]{Palatino}
```

And compile with this:

```
xelatex main.tex
```

I use:

```
``word''
```

But the quotes are never curly as they should be. I can only get the curly quotes when using the default font.

Ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use the option `Ligatures=TeX` (or `Mapping=tex-text` for older version of fontspec), e.g.:

```
\setmainfont [Ligatures={Common,TeX}, Numbers={OldStyle}]{Palatino}
```

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't work for me. https://img.skitch.com/20110713-kp3sbip3qw4e773kh4wgabk6jq.jpg

Comment: One should also use `\setmainfont`, as `\setromanfont` is deprecated in recent versions of **fontspec**.

Comment: Yes, it works: "curly" quotes in Palatino are not curly. :)

Comment: @egreg - that didn't do it either

Comment: Oh! Really? That's kind of odd, no?

Comment: Just tried with Baskerville and it worked fine! Thanks a lot guys

Comment: @Honza: Looking at your picture, you can actually tell that the quotes around _cool_ follow the 66-99 pattern (representing where the the signs are thicker and thinner), the quotes around _yo_, however, seem to be wrong, it looks like the source of that might be `''yo''`.

Comment: @egreg: indeed `\setromanfont` is long deprecated, I copied from the question blindly.

Comment: I just tried and this solved my problem with Bookman Old Style, so thank you very much.   Can someone explain what these options do? and why I need them in this case? And why all the other documentation I was digging through failed to mention them?  Is this a XeLaTeX problem, or something more widespread?

Comment: @AgilePro: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193414/729

Answer (score 0):

I found a useful fix at the link below, after many hours of searching:

https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/889

Basically change

```
\setmonofont[]{$monofont$}
```

to

```
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-ansi]{$monofont$}
```