# What is happening to the quotes?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, punctuation, ligatures

Here is my MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
``abcde''
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

If I comment out the `\defaultfontfeatures` line, the result is:

[image]

If I remove both that and the use of `xltxtra` (and obviously the `\setromanfont`), I get:

[image]

So the question is: what is happening to the quotation marks? What does `xltxtra` do to them and what does `\defaultfontfeatures` do?

Comment: OK OK, `\setromanfont` is not necessary, but I don't want to redo the screenshots just to remove it :).

Comment: Do you know what version of `xelatex` / `xltxtra` you are using? I cannot reproduce this on TeXLive 2014 with XeLaTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 and `xltxtra` v0.5e. I always get smart quotes...

Comment: TeXShop's console tells me `This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013) restricted \write18 enabled.`. As for `xltxtra`, on the .sty I find `2010/09/20 v0.5e Improvements for the "XeLaTeX" format`.

Comment: Would you please change the example word? Don't force me to do it. I *know* what the word means.

Comment: It appears [newer versions of `fontspec`](https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/commit/d96eb22783691db4c5f8a8ec715c64452493105a) set the `Ligatures=TeX` option by default which implies `Mapping=tex-text`. [`xltxtra`](https://github.com/wspr/xltxtra/blob/v0.5/xltxtra.dtx#L824) sets `Mapping=tex-text` for the default fonts it sets, hence, your invocation of `\setromanfont` removes that mapping. I'm not sure what causes the behaviour of your third iteration.

Comment: Do you know which version of `fontspec` you have installed?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your code a bit. Note that I compiled the code snippets with MacTeX2013, not the current MacTeX2014.

Comment: @egreg - see my edits.

Comment: I was just about to do that. I just found out removing `\setromanfont` solves the issue. `fontspec.sty` says `2013/05/20 v2.3c`.

Comment: @MickG - If you remove the `\setromanfont` instruction (or an equivalent `\setmainfont` directive), you won't get Times Roman as the text font for your document. Do you *want* to stay with Computer Modern?

Comment: No. I was merely observing that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some years ago, the package `xltxtra` was recommended for usage with XeLaTeX, but it isn't any more. To the contrary, it is *not* recommended to load `xltxtra`, unless you really need its extra functions (you usually don't).

The `\setromanfont` command has been deprecated some years ago, favoring the clearer command `\setmainfont`. The `Mapping=tex-text` option has been changed into

```
Ligatures=TeX
```

and, with the most recent version of `fontspec` on TeX Live 2014 it is even unnecessary to specify it. So, with an up-to-date TeX distribution, the correct code is

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
``parola''.
\end{document}
```

On an older TeX distribution such as TeX Live 2013, you need

```
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
```

Don't specify the option in `\defaultfontfeatures`, because it would affect also the monospaced font (in case you declare it) and you don't want that.

---

Now to your question.

1. The `Ligatures=TeX` option (formerly `Mapping=tex-text`) makes the usual ligatures to work also with XeLaTeX; so ``` `` ``` is mapped to `“`, `''` to `”`, `--` to the en-dash, `---` to the em-dash (there are some others). This explains the first case
2. If you remove the `Ligatures=TeX` option, these ligatures are not defined, so you get ``` `` ``` and `''` as expected.
3. If you don't load `fontspec` (done by `xltxtra`), XeLaTeX loads the usual fonts, which *do* have the ligatures. But, of course, accented characters will probably not work.
4. If you load `fontspec` but don't use `\setmainfont`, the standard Latin Modern fonts are used, which are preloaded with `Ligatures=TeX`.