# Does vref of varioref work with page numbers which are not built-in arabic?

Tags: varioref

I have page numbers which are not arabic. I use page numbers in Burmese, ၁, ၂, ၃, ၄, etc., which are equivalent to 1, 2, 3, 4. I use the following to turn default arabic page numbers to Burmese numbers:

```
%%% Auto numbering in Myanmar %%%
%This macro is to produce myanmar numbering by adopting the thai numbering method
\makeatletter  
\def\@mmnum#1{\expandafter\@@mmnum\number#1\@nil}  
\def\@@mmnum#1{%  
  \ifx#1\@nil  
  \else  
  \char\numexpr#1+"1040\relax  % 1040 is zero character for Burmese.
  \expandafter\@@mmnum\fi  
}  
\renewcommand\@arabic{\@mmnum} % to reset number in \arabic to \mmnum
```

When I tried vref, even if the referenced item is on the facing/or preceding page, I still get the result with the page number like "Figure 1 on page 23" instead of "Figure 1 on the facing/previous page". If the reference and the referenced item are on the same page, the result seems to work. I get just "Figure 1" without the page number if it's on the same page on which vref is used to refer to it.

How can I get the expected result for preceding/facing page without the page number even if my page numbers are not arabic?

Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}


%%% Font related tweaks
\defaultfontfeatures{Script=Myanmar,Mapping=tex-text} 
\fontspec[Script=Myanmar, BoldFont={Padauk Bold}, ]{Padauk}
\setmainfont[Color=tungsten,
                UprightFont={Padauk},
                BoldFont={Padauk Bold},
                ItalicFont={Padauk},
                BoldItalicFont={Padauk Bold},
                SmallCapsFont={Padauk},
                SlantedFont={Padauk}]{Padauk}
                [Renderer=Harfbuzz,Script=Myanmar]


\def\reftextfaceafter{\reftextvario{Page is near}{Page is near} Page is near}%%
\def\reftextafter {Page is near}%
\def\reftextfacebefore{Page is near}%
\def\reftextbefore {Page is near}%
\def\reftextcurrent{\reftextvario{Same page}{Sagem page} Same page}%
\def\reftextfaraway#1{(“If the referenced item is near, I should not see this.”).~\pageref{#1}}%
\def\reftextpagerange#1#2{on QQQQ~\pageref{#1}--\pageref{#2}}%
\def\reftextlabelrange#1#2{\ref{#1} to~\ref{#2}}%

%%% Auto numbering in Myanmar %%%
%This macro is to produce myanmar numbering by adopting the thai numbering method
\makeatletter  
\def\@mmnum#1{\expandafter\@@mmnum\number#1\@nil}  
\def\@@mmnum#1{%  
  \ifx#1\@nil  
  \else  
  \char\numexpr#1+"1040\relax  
  \expandafter\@@mmnum\fi  
}  
\renewcommand\@arabic{\@mmnum} % to reset number in \arabic to \mmnum 

\begin{document}
\section{Figures}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{An example figure}
%%%%%% This is okay
See figure -- \vref*{fig:example}
%%%%%%
\label{fig:example}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{Another example figure}
\label{fig:other}
\end{figure}
\newpage
Same reference code, different output:
\begin{verbatim}
See the \vpageref[above figure][figure]{fig:other} and
the \vpageref[above figure][figure]{fig:example}.
\end{verbatim}
See the \vpageref[above figure][figure]{fig:other} and
the \vpageref[above figure][figure]{fig:example}.
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext


%%%%% This is not okay 
See figure \vref*{fig:other} ----

See figure \vref*{fig:example} ----

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mensch. I've added the code snippet I used to test. The font I used can be downloaded here: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Padauk

Comment: Clarification question: when I run your code I get the output `See the above figure and the LLLLL ၁` for the first references and `fig. ၂ LLLLL ၂ sdfsdfdf fig. ၁ LLLLL ၁` for the second references. When I remove the `\reftext` redefinitions I get `See the above figure and the on page ၁` for the first references. Do you get the same output? If yes, how should it be changed, i.e., what is the exact desired output in these four cases?

Comment: Hi @Marijn, I've added one more code section. For the least few lines which are %%%%% This is not okay  See figure \vref*{fig:other} \vref*{fig:example} \end{document}, I expect "Page is near" instead of “If the referenced item is near, I should not see this.”  The exact result I got: See figure၂ (“If the referenced item is near, I should not see this.”). ၂ —- See figure၁ (“If the referenced item is near, I should not see this.”). ၁ —-

Comment: Basically, for my case with Burmese numerals, vref is always returning reftextfaraway when the reference and the referenced item are not on the same page even if they are close.

Comment: @PyiSoe A suggestion: if you could provide your example with a font already available in the regular TeX installations (so that people don't need to install a font just to test it), it would increase the chance of your question getting attention. I don't know if it exists, but if it does, it would definitely ease things.

Comment: Hi @gusbrs, unfortunately, no regular latex installation comes with any font for our language.

Comment: @PyiSoe I was afraid you'd say so. It is as easy as it gets then. ;-)

Comment: Note that in Ubuntu the Padauk font is installed automatically as dependency of the distribution package `texlive-lang-other` (and therefore `texlive-full`) so anyone that installed TeX Live through the Ubuntu repositories has the font. It is also a dependency of various Ubuntu desktop packages (presumably to provide Myanmar support), so probably also available if you installed TeX Live through `tlmgr`.

Comment: @Marijn, thanks for pointing out that there are installations with readily available Padauk font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different answer with an altogether different approach.

Since the latest update, `zref-vario` allows one to specify the `zref` property to use for page comparisons, instead of `page`, thus lifting the restriction of `varioref` of requiring Arabic page numbering to distinguish "nearby" from "far away" pages.

This is done with the `pageprop` option, which can be set to `abspage` provided by the `zref-abspage` `zref` module, so that you have a page counter used for page comparisons which is independent from the printed representation of your page references, and thus you can use whatever page numbering scheme you may fancy.

What you may or may not consider a downside, is that this works with the `zref` referencing system rather than the standard one. Anyway, the example below adjusts your MWE to it:

```tex
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}

%%% Font related tweaks
\defaultfontfeatures{Script=Myanmar,Mapping=tex-text}
\fontspec[Script=Myanmar, BoldFont={Padauk Bold}, ]{Padauk}
\setmainfont[Color=tungsten,
                UprightFont={Padauk},
                BoldFont={Padauk Bold},
                ItalicFont={Padauk},
                BoldItalicFont={Padauk Bold},
                SmallCapsFont={Padauk},
                SlantedFont={Padauk}]{Padauk}
                [Renderer=Harfbuzz,Script=Myanmar]

%%% Auto numbering in Myanmar %%%
%This macro is to produce myanmar numbering by adopting the thai numbering method
\makeatletter
\def\@mmnum#1{\expandafter\@@mmnum\number#1\@nil}
\def\@@mmnum#1{%
  \ifx#1\@nil
  \else
  \char\numexpr#1+"1040\relax
  \expandafter\@@mmnum\fi
}%"
\renewcommand\@arabic{\@mmnum} % to reset number in \arabic to \mmnum

\usepackage{zref-vario}
\usepackage{zref-abspage}
\zvsetup{pageprop=abspage}

\begin{document}

\section{Figures}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{An example figure}

%%%%%% This is okay
See \zvref{fig:example}
%%%%%%

\zlabel{fig:example}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{Another example figure}
\zlabel{fig:other}
\end{figure}

\newpage

Same reference code, different output:

\begin{verbatim}
See the \zvpageref[vcurrent={above figure},vother={figure}]{fig:other} and
the \zvpageref[vcurrent={above figure},vother={figure}]{fig:example}.
\end{verbatim}
See the \zvpageref[vcurrent={above figure},vother={figure}]{fig:other} and
the \zvpageref[vcurrent={above figure},vother={figure}]{fig:example}.

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

%%%%% This is now okay
See \zvref{fig:other} ---

See \zvref{fig:example} ---

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**: Some fun. This approach allows us to use `varioref`'s enhanced page references with the awesome `sillypage` package:

```tex
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{sillypage}

\usepackage{zref-vario}
\usepackage{zref-abspage}
\zvsetup{pageprop=abspage}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{silly}

\chapter{Figures}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{An example figure}
\zlabel{fig:example}
\end{figure}

\blindtext[3]

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{Another example figure}
\zlabel{fig:other}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\blindtext[3]

\bigskip{}

See \zvref{fig:other}.

See \zvref{fig:example}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @gusbrs, thank you so much for your help. I think the second approach looks promising. I'll try that out and let know how it goes after testing.

Comment: What I've been thinking as a workaround is just to replace the 0, 1, 2,..., 9 with ၀, ၁, ၂, ..., ၉ in the Burmese font using some kind of font editor software like FontForge. I am not sure about the consequences though.

Comment: @PyiSoe Hard-coding the change at the font itself sounds a little too "brute force" to me. But, well, who knows? Maybe it works. Technically, as far as I understand, it more or less is what the `mapdigits` / LuaLaTeX answer does, without editing the font.

Comment: after updating `\usepackage{zref-vario} \usepackage{zref-abspage}` packages, I can produce the desired output. And I hope this is one and only last obstacle I encountered regarding auto numbering and referencing. It seems everything else in LaTex is already working fine for me. Bye the way, I also feel  that changing the font itself should be the last resort. I've asked for others' opinion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651157/how-automatic-numbering-would-behave-if-0-through-9-are-replaced-with-matching-u). Again, I really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @gusbrs, when I add ```\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "my_MM"  \XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping = 2 ```, zvref doesn't produce the desired result. If ```\XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping = 0/1```, it can produce the desired result. My head starts spinning again :). I have no idea why XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping can affect the way zvref wroks.

Comment: @PyiSoe, I also have no idea. Indeed, it surprises me that line breaking and word spacing could affect the cross-referencing mechanism. Anyway, I suggest you ask a new question with a minimal working example of the problem, and explaining how the results differ from what you expect. And, given the nature of the problem, it will probably require someone with more knowledge than myself...

Comment: yes, I'll post a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution gives me the result I want as well. It also works with these two important properties which are very important for me:

```
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "my_MM"  %Myanmar line and character breaks
\XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping = 2
```

1. create a mapping file, mmdigit_mapping.map with content

```
; FC ... 
LHSName "Digits"
RHSName "BurmeseDigits"

pass(Unicode)
U+0030 <> U+1040 ;
U+0031 <> U+1041 ;
U+0032 <> U+1042 ;
U+0033 <> U+1043 ;
U+0034 <> U+1044 ;
U+0035 <> U+1045 ;
U+0036 <> U+1046 ;
U+0037 <> U+1047 ;
U+0038 <> U+1048 ;
U+0039 <> U+1049 ;
```

2. Run `teckit_compile mmdigit_mapping.map` to get `mmdigit_mapping.tec` file. I am not sure why my macos
   already has `teckit_compile`. Probably one will need to get the installer from here:
   https://software.sil.org/teckit/

And then I create my *.tex file  like below and test :

```
%!TeX program = XeLaTex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[twoside, openright]{book}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "my_MM"  %Myanmar line and character breaks
\XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping = 2

\usepackage[nospace]{varioref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setmainfont[
        % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193412/what-is-happening-to-the-quotes
        Ligatures = TeX,
        WordSpace = 1,
        UprightFont = {Padauk Book},
        BoldFont = {Padauk Book Bold},
        ItalicFont = {Padauk Book},
        BoldItalicFont = {Padauk Book Bold},
        SmallCapsFont = {Padauk Book},
        SlantedFont = {Padauk Book},
        % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498689/how-to-use-locale-numbering-custom-numbering-for-burmese
        % Mapping=mmdigit_mapping
    ]
    {Padauk Book}
    [Renderer = Graphite, RawFeature = {Tear drop style washwe=True}]

\newcommand{\myPgNoFnt}
    {\fontspec[
            % the mapping
            Mapping = mmdigit_mapping,
            Script = Myanmar,
            Scale = MatchLowercase, 
            BoldFont = {Padauk Book Bold}
        ]
        {Padauk Book}
        \selectfont}

\newcommand{\myRefCntFnt}
{\fontspec[
        Mapping = mmdigit_mapping,
        Script = Myanmar,
        Scale = MatchLowercase, 
        BoldFont = {Padauk Book Bold}
    ]
    {Padauk Book}
    \selectfont} 
    
\newcommand{\myCptFnt}
{\fontspec[
        Mapping = mmdigit_mapping,
        Script = Myanmar,
        Scale = MatchLowercase, 
        BoldFont = {Pyidaungsu Bold}
    ]
    {Pyidaungsu}
    %[Renderer=Graphite, RawFeature={Tear drop style washwe=True}]
    \selectfont} 

%\def\reftextfaceafter {on the \reftextvario{facing}{next} page}%
%\def\reftextfacebefore{on the \reftextvario{facing}{preceding} page}%
%\def\reftextafter     {on the \reftextvario{following}{next} page}%
%\def\reftextbefore    {on the \reftextvario{preceding}{previous} page}%
%\def\reftextcurrent   {on \reftextvario{this}{the current} page}%
%\def\reftextfaraway#1{on page~\pageref{#1}}%

\def\reftextfaceafter {\reftextvario{တစ်ဖက်}{နောက်}စာမျက်နှာ~}%
\def\reftextfacebefore{\reftextvario{တစ်ဖက်}{ရှေ့}စာမျက်နှာ~}% အရင် ပြီးခဲ့တဲ့ 
\def\reftextafter     {\reftextvario{လာမဲ့}{နောက်}စာမျက်နှာ~}%
\def\reftextbefore    {\reftextvario{ပြီးခဲ့တဲ့}{‌ရှေ့}စာမျက်နှာ~}%
\def\reftextcurrent   {\reftextvario{}{}}%
\def\reftextfaraway#1{စာမျက်နှာ~{\myRefCntFnt\pageref{#1}}~}%

\newcommand{\myvref}[1] {
    {\myRefCntFnt{\vpageref[]{#1}}}{\myRefCntFnt{\Ref*{#1}}}
} 

\renewcommand{\figurename}{ပုံ}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyfoot[C]{\bfseries\myPgNoFnt\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{headings}{%
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\bfseries\myPgNoFnt\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\pagestyle{headings}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{ပုံ}
\DeclareCaptionFont{captionfont}{\myCptFnt}
\captionsetup[figure]{
    singlelinecheck=false,
    justification=raggedright,
    font={captionfont, bf, small, onehalfspacing}}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{custom}
    {~#1 \textbf{#2}~}  %to get "Figure (1)", "Figure [1]", etc
% Separator style
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{custom}{- } % to get "Figure (1):", "Figure(1) - Some caption" etc
% Caption format    
\DeclareCaptionFormat{custom}
    {#1#2\small #3}
\captionsetup{
    format=custom,
    labelformat=custom,
    labelsep=custom}
    
\labelformat{figure}{ပုံ~{\myRefCntFnt #1}}

\addtolength{\topmargin}{-3.0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{အစမ်းပုံ ၁}
\label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}

----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig1} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig2} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig3} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig4} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig5} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig6} -----------------------




\newpage
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{အစမ်းပုံ ၂}
\label{fig:fig2}
\end{figure}

----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig1} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig2} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig3} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig4} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig5} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig6} -----------------------

\newpage
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{အစမ်းပုံ ၃}
\label{fig:fig3}
\end{figure}

----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig1} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig2} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig3} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig4} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig5} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig6} -----------------------

\newpage
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{အစမ်းပုံ ၄}
\label{fig:fig4}
\end{figure}

----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig1} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig2} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig3} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig4} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig5} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig6} -----------------------

\newpage
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{အစမ်းပုံ ၅}
\label{fig:fig5}
\end{figure}

----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig1} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig2} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig3} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig4} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig5} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig6} -----------------------

\newpage
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{အစမ်းပုံ ၆}
\label{fig:fig6}
\end{figure}

----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig1} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig2} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig3} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig4} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig5} -----------------------

\noindent----------------------- \myvref{fig:fig6} -----------------------

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use `babel` and `luatex` I think there is a clean solution to this, which is to use the `mapdigits` option from `\babelprovide`. Of course, the effects of loading a `babel` locale and setting a language are not limited to this mapping, but I presume these would also be desirable.

```latex
% !TeX program = LuaLaTeX
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[mapdigits, import, main]{burmese}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}

%%% Font related tweaks
\defaultfontfeatures{Script=Myanmar,Mapping=tex-text}
\fontspec[Script=Myanmar, BoldFont={Padauk Bold}]{Padauk}
\setmainfont[
  Color=tungsten,
  UprightFont={Padauk},
  BoldFont={Padauk Bold},
  ItalicFont={Padauk},
  BoldItalicFont={Padauk Bold},
  SmallCapsFont={Padauk},
  SlantedFont={Padauk}
]{Padauk}[Renderer=Harfbuzz,Script=Myanmar]

\def\reftextfaceafter{\reftextvario{Page is near}{Page is near} Page is near}%%
\def\reftextafter {Page is near}%
\def\reftextfacebefore{Page is near}%
\def\reftextbefore {Page is near}%
\def\reftextcurrent{\reftextvario{Same page}{Sagem page} Same page}%
\def\reftextfaraway#1{(“If the referenced item is near, I should not see this.”).~\pageref{#1}}%
\def\reftextpagerange#1#2{on QQQQ~\pageref{#1}--\pageref{#2}}%
\def\reftextlabelrange#1#2{\ref{#1} to~\ref{#2}}%

\begin{document}
\section{Figures}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{An example figure}
%%%%%% This is okay
See figure -- \vref*{fig:example}
%%%%%%
\label{fig:example}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{Another example figure}
\label{fig:other}
\end{figure}
\newpage
Same reference code, different output:
\begin{verbatim}
See the \vpageref[above figure][figure]{fig:other} and
the \vpageref[above figure][figure]{fig:example}.
\end{verbatim}
See the \vpageref[above figure][figure]{fig:other} and
the \vpageref[above figure][figure]{fig:example}.
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

%%%%% This is okay now
See figure \vref*{fig:other} ----

See figure \vref*{fig:example} ----

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I am currently using XeLaTex. The reason is that, according to what I've read online, it's the best engine for our language. And it also supports right justification pretty well. By the way, I need to write the book mostly in Burmese. I am not sure how much support babel can provide for my language. Anyway, I'll try what you have suggested above. Just in case you may want to have a look at my document: https://github.com/pyiso80/book-programming-with-java/blob/master/Programming%20with%20Java.pdf

Comment: @PyiSoe Well, unfortunately, I really have no idea of the specific needs of your language, and what different packages handle it better. You are better placed than me to judge. Still, that was the best I could come up with. :)