# Manually specifying a system TTF font seems to break curly/smart quotes

Tags: xetex, fontspec, verbatim

The following code...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin = 0.4in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

    \fontspec[Scale=3]{URW Bookman L Light}

    ``These quotes are not curly!'' \\ \\ \par

    Examples: ` `` '' '

\end{document}
```

...produces the following disheartening output when run through XƎLatex.

[image: Screenshot of rendered TeX code]

As soon as I remove the `\fontspec` instruction, everything works perfectly using TeX's default font.

*How do I specify my own (TTF, system) font, and use curly quotes?*

<sub>(Note: I'm using TeX to typeset some emails so they print with precise formatting; I've never used it before, and I only have about 7 hours’ experience using it. If there's anything braindead you see in the code above please don't hesitate to mention it.)</sub>

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23004/15925 help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Do you mean curly quotation marks rather than curly braces? My answer below assumes that 'braces' is a typo. Please explain the problem with braces if I am mistaken in this assumption!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `Mapping=tex-text` or `Ligatures=TeX` to the `\fontspec` options (see [§11.1 of the docs](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf#page=39)).

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell `fontspec` to emulate traditional TeX typesetting features, such as turning backticks and straight quotation marks into curly quotation marks. You can do this using `Mapping` but the recommended syntax is `Ligatures=TeX`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin = 0.4in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

    \fontspec[Scale=3, Ligatures=TeX]{URW Bookman L Light}

    ``These quotes are not curly!'' \\ \\ \par

    Examples: ` `` '' '

\end{document}
```

[image: curly quotes]

I recommend taking a look at `csquotes` which helps manage quotation mark-up in a flexible and consistent way.

Comment: It would be better to suggest `\setmainfont` rather than `\fontspec` in the document body.

Comment: @egreg I wasn't sure that the OP wanted to set it as the main font. But it might be better to set up a different font family, at least.